# APT complains of broken/unmet dependencies for my package, but they are available in my repository. How to fix?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, packaging

I manage an apt repository, for package `PACKAGE`, which has dependency `(DEPENDENCY<<1.2)`.
Both `PACKAGE` and `DEPENDENCY` are available in my repository.

We just released a version of `DEPENDENCY` (version 4.0.0), and now installing the same `PACKAGE` **on a completely clean machine** fails with the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 PACKAGE : Depends: DEPENDENCY (< 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I check the versions of DEPENDENCY available, I can see that there are known packages which meet the `<< 1.2` requirement:

```
sudo apt list -a DEPENDENCY
Listing... Done
DEPENDENCY/stable 4.0.0 all
DEPENDENCY/stable 1.1.12 all
DEPENDENCY/stable 1.1.11 all
DEPENDENCY/stable 1.1.10 all
...
```

Since I actually manage the package *AND* the dependency I can fix this on the repository side, but how? Why doesn't `apt` recognise the correct dependencies?

(Doing `apt --fix-broken` won't work because the packages are somehow broken on the server side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APT doesn’t resolve versions of packages based on requirements, but rather based on availability (and priorities). Put another way, it is really designed to work with coherent repositories, *i.e.* repositories with single versions of packages, where all related packages can be installed with the versions in the repository. (That’s how the Debian repositories work most of the time, and is a requirement for the release repositories.)

Even though `DEPENDENCY` is available in multiple versions in the same suite, APT will consider the highest version only, 4.0.0, unless told otherwise.

You’ll probably need to help APT resolve the situation manually:

```
apt install PACKAGE DEPENDENCY=1.1.12
```

and even then I’m not 100% sure that will work.

As a general solution, you’d have to use different suites in your repository, and make sure `PACKAGE` and `DEPENDENCY` are present in mutually-acceptable versions in the same suite; version 4.0.0 of `DEPENDENCY` would therefore go in a different suite, without `PACKAGE`, until `PACKAGE` is available in a compatible version.

Comment: thank you for the reply! It looks as though I should rethink the whole structure of my repository.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem I was having was that I changed the download source for packages. in settings > about > download source. I changed it to a server nearer to my location as this enhanced faster app downloads particular for flatpak packages.

I solved it by returning the setting back to "main" and everything worked brilliantly. I experienced this problem when i was trying to install barrier, a program that allows you to share your mouse across different devices and cross operating systems.

Comment: Your answer seems to be in the viewpoint of someone *using* a particular repository. But the question was about fixing the problem as someone *managing* that repository.